# How do I fix the BOSH deploy error `Missing properties: resource_pool.availability_zone`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bosh-deployer

When I attempt a BOSH deploy (`bosh -d nginx-ntp-xip-aws.yml -n deploy`), I get the following error:

```
Deploying
---------

Director task 311
  Started preparing deployment > Preparing deployment. Done     (00:00:01)

  Started preparing package compilation > Finding packages to compile. Done (00:00:00)

  Started creating missing vms > nginx_ntp_xip/0 (23ec1c94-f415-4922-9914-42fe5b3f2b38). Failed: Missing properties: resource_pool.availability_zone (00:00:05)

Error 100: Missing properties: resource_pool.availability_zone
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `availability_zone` property was missing from `vm_types` section of my BOSH director's *cloud-config*. Here's my `azs` section from my *cloud-config*:

```
azs:
- name: z1
  cloud_properties:
    availability_zone: us-east-1a
```

I updated the `vm_types` stanza in `cloud-config.yml`:

```
vm_types:
- name: t2.nano
  cloud_properties:
    instance_type: t2.nano
    availability_zone: us-east-1a
    ephemeral_disk:
      size: 4_000
      type: gp2
```

I then updated my BOSH director's cloud-config:

```
bosh update cloud-config cloud-config.yml
```

My subsequent deploy succeeded:

```
bosh -d nginx-ntp-xip-aws.yml -n deploy
```